# How to set a fixed width of several columns in sheet by openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I would like to create a `for` loop for columns from `B` to `AG` for which it will do the `width = 3` in xlsx file. I am using `openpyxl` library.
Is there any method to get the index of letters from the `xlsx sheet` and create such a loop according to it?

```
# settings for userAccountControl sheet:
sheet_3_name = 'userAccountControl'
flag_col_width = 3
wb_master[sheet_3_name].column_dimensions['B'].width = flag_col_width
...
...
wb_master[sheet_3_name].column_dimensions['AG'].width = flag_col_width
```

Comment: You want to know how to loop over column letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start by making a list of all possible column letters in Excel (`'A'` to `'XFD'`) then make a slice/loop based on the range of columns you need to set width for.

To make this out, you can use [`openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html#openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter) :

```
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter

col_xl = [get_column_letter(idx) for idx in range(1, 16384+1)] #16384 is Excel's limit

start_col, end_col = ("B", "AG")
sheet_3_name = 'userAccountControl'
flag_col_width = 3

for col in col_xl[col_xl.index(start_col):col_xl.index(end_col)+1]:
    wb_master[sheet_3_name].column_dimensions[col].width = flag_col_width
```